# Formatting a specific cell in a table

Tags: tables, formatting, rules

I am trying to format a table with no success. I basically trying to add a line after the case 3 (first set). There should basically be a separation between the first set of cases (after -7) with the second. But I want the line to pass through all columns except the first one.

```
\begin{table} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline 
  node         & a   & b & c & d &e & f & g & h \\
               & t & S & (ps) & (ps) & (ps) & (ps) &   & d \\
  \hline
               & a      & Case I    & 110  & +000   & 100  & 100  & 0 &  0 \\
               & b  & Case II   & 100  & +100   & 100  & 10  & 0 & -10 \\
  1\textit{} &           & Case III  & 100  & -00   & 10  & 10  &0 & 00 \\
  T         & a     & Case I    & 00  & +0   & 1  & 0  & 0 &  0 \\
  o         & B   & Case II   & 00  & +0   & 10  & 10  & 0 &  0 \\
               &           & Case III  & 100  & -300   & 100  & 100  & 0 & -0 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\cline{2-9}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your table may be improved by redesigning it a bit. The material in the first column, headed by the word "Node", seems to apply to the entire table, and not just to some rows. If this impression is correct, the information contained in the first column really belongs in the table's *caption*. For instance, the caption might say, "x nm Tech Node". I would also suggest that you (i) get rid of all vertical bars and (ii) use the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to obtain well-spaced horizontal lines.

(The header row and column information was modified because it apparently contains sensitive information that shouldn't have been posted in the open. The "x" stubs replace the real information.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\newcommand\phm{\phantom{$-$}} % invisible "minus" sign
\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{x\,nm Tech Node}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llcccccc@{}} 
\toprule 
x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x\\
x&x&(ps)&(ps)&(ps)&(ps)&&x (ps)\\
\midrule
z   & Case I&190&+0&190&200 &0&\phm0\\
z& Case II&163&+1&164&170&0&$-1$\\
       & Case III&141&$-3$&138&155&0&$-7$\\
\cmidrule{1-8}
z  & Case I&221&+0&221&230&0&\phm0\\
z& Case II&164&+0&164&170&0&\phm0\\
       & Case III&154&$-3$&151&160&0&$-5$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgive me for using your code :-)

Comment: And I've upvoted yours, of course :-)

Comment: @sowhardh - I rejected your suggested edits but implemented a different set of changes. I also uploaded a new image file. Hope you're OK with that.

Answer (score 6):

Just some improvments to [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227515/27635) with the `siunitx` package (note the `S` columns):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{\SI{0}{\nm} zzzz}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l
                   l
                   S[table-format=3.0]
                   S[table-format=-1.0,explicit-sign=+]
                   S[table-format=3.0]
                   S[table-format=3.0]
                   S[table-format=1.0]
                   S[table-format=-1.0]@{}}
\toprule
xxx&xxx&{xxx}&{xxx}&{xxx}&{xxx}&{xxx}&{xxx}\\
yyy&yyy&{(ps)}&{(ps)}&{(ps)}&{(ps)}&&{zzz (ps)}\\
\midrule
xxxx   & Case I&190&0&190&200 &0&0\\
xxxx   & Case II&163&1&164&170&0&-1\\
       & Case III&141&-3&138&155&0&-7\\
\cmidrule{1-8}
xxxx   & Case I&221&0&221&230&0&0\\
xxxx   & Case II&164&0&164&170&0&0\\
       & Case III&154&-3&151&160&0&-5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've upvoted your answer for the use of `\SI` and the `S` column type. :-) I might be tempted to specify `S[table-format=2.0]`, rather than just `S`, to obtain a more-natural looking centering effect. However, that's purely a matter of taste.

Comment: @Mico `S[table-format=2.0]` gives overfull boxes...

Comment: I think it would be perfectly OK to ignore the `overfull \hbox` warnings in this case. That, or change to `S[table-format=3.1]` ...

Comment: Why not also the fourth column as `S`? And the others as well, of course. However, the last specification should be `table-format=-1.0`

Comment: @egreg - Setting `table-format=-1.0` centers the numbers and makes the minus signs stick out to the left, thereby creating a not-so-centered look. `2.0` or `3.1` avoids this problem.

Comment: @Mico Not at all. Try with `{$-1$}` instead of `{Delta}` in the header and you'll see.

Comment: @Mico egreg is right, in my opinion.

Comment: He usually is... :-)

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I must have looked at something slightly different before...

Comment: @egreg All the columns are `S` now... Thanks for the suggestion, as always.